# Parallelizing BLAKE

Tags: c, openmp

I have big problem to parallelize [BLAKE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLAKE_(hash_function)) using OMP. They sugested in specification that it is possible to parallelize "column step" and "diagonal step". I try to do this but the results are opposite that I expected (10 times slower than one-threaded). I need a little help from more experienced users of OMP, because now I have no idea how to parallelize this loop :(

Update:

I know that authors of BLAKE published BLAKE2, which is improved (faster) version of BLAKE, but it has different implemention (tree-hashing) than BLAKE and this is quite hard to understand for me. My task is to do compare of one-threaded and multi-threaded implementation using OMP. So I try to do this on implementation that I understand. I am not expert of OMP, I want to make BLAKE multi-threaded in the easiest way possible. I must do proper implementation with OMP even if the performance may not be better. (Sorry for my english, I hope that you understand me)
This is part of my code:

```
 #pragma omp parallel shared(n)
  {
 for(round=0; round<n; ++round) 
 {
/* column step, I want to run this 4 G32 functions in parallel, but don't know,
   that is proper approach to this problem */
        #pragma omp critical 
     G32( 0, 4, 8,12, 0);
        #pragma omp critical 
     G32( 1, 5, 9,13, 1);
        #pragma omp critical 
     G32( 2, 6,10,14, 2);
        #pragma omp critical 
     G32( 3, 7,11,15, 3);    

/* diagonal step, and same here */
        #pragma omp critical 
     G32( 0, 5,10,15, 4);
        #pragma omp critical 
     G32( 1, 6,11,12, 5);
        #pragma omp critical 
     G32( 2, 7, 8,13, 6);
        #pragma omp critical 
     G32( 3, 4, 9,14, 7);
}
}
```

And this is G32 function:

```
#define G32(a,b,c,d,i)\
 do { \
v[a] = ADD32(v[a],v[b])+XOR32(m[sigma[round][2*i]], c32[sigma[round][2*i+1]]);\
v[d] = ROT32(XOR32(v[d],v[a]),16);\
v[c] = ADD32(v[c],v[d]);\
v[b] = ROT32(XOR32(v[b],v[c]),12);\
v[a] = ADD32(v[a],v[b])+XOR32(m[sigma[round][2*i+1]], c32[sigma[round][2*i]]);\
v[d] = ROT32(XOR32(v[d],v[a]), 8);\
v[c] = ADD32(v[c],v[d]);\
v[b] = ROT32(XOR32(v[b],v[c]), 7);\
} while (0)
```

Comment: What did your OMP look like?

Comment: That claim is about SIMD parallelization. If you want to use multiple threads, consider Blake2*p which allows compression function calls in parallel, which works much better with threads.

Comment: The BLAKE2*p variants are quite simple. You divide the message into blocks, and distribute those blocks among 4 threads, and finally you hash the output of those 4 partial hashes again to get the final hash.

Comment: But is the hash the same like non-divided message?

Answer (score 2):

I think the kind of parallelization they had in mind was exploiting SIMD instrctions under modern CPUs. The problem with OMP-style parallelization in this case is two-fold:

- The G32 tasks are too "small" or "short" so that the overhead with respect to starting the tasks in different threads and joining is too great in comparison.
- False Sharing: The memory locations that are read and modified in the tasks are too close together. They probably share a cache line. This is bad because this requires special synchronization and makes read/writes from different threads very slow.